# Adding slf4j-simple.jar doesn't solve: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j

On starting spring boot application, I get:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
```

In maven dependency tree, I see following occurrences of slf4j:

```
org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.11:jar:2.5.21:compile
org.clapper:grizzled-slf4j_2.11:jar:1.3.2:compile
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.13.3:compile
org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
```

At [this link](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder), it mentions to add slf4j-simple.jar to solve it. I did so:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha1</version>
</dependency>
```

....but I still get the error.

How to solve it?

Comment: you don't have to add slf4j Spring Boot Starter Logging comes wiht this dependency. Can you show your pom.xml?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, pinged you the pom in chat room

Comment: why do you exclude logback

Comment: This I got in a legacy project. And if I undo the exclusion, I get error:Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext] 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All tokens consumed but was expecting "}"

Comment: OK, I solved above issue after making some changes in logback.xml. Would post if slf4j issue goes away or not.